# NavigationLink in contextMenu

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've been experimenting with NavigationLink in a contextMenu, and have run into this issue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("foo")
                    .contextMenu {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("foo context destination")) { //works
                            Text("foo context")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.all)

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("bar destination")) { //works
                    Text("bar")
                        .contextMenu {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("bar context destination")) {  //does not work
                                Text("bar context")
                            }
                        }
                }
                .padding(.all)
            } //VStack
        } //NavigationView
    } //body
} //ContentView
```

As shown in the code, NavigationLink within a contextMenu seems to work for 'foo context' but not for 'bar context'.  The difference is that 'foo' is wrapped in a NavigationLink, but 'bar' is not.  I would appreciate any suggestions for solving the issue with 'bar context' navigation.

Edit:  To clarify, I would like to find a way to navigate to "bar destination" by tapping "bar", OR navigate to "bar context destination" by tapping "bar context" in the contextMenu.  The problem seems to be that when "bar" is wrapped in NavigationLink, then NavigationLink in the contextMenu attached to "bar" is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to your code so that both "foo" and "bar" works.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("foo")
                    .contextMenu {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("foo context destination")) { //works
                                Text("foo context")
                            }
                    }
                .padding(.all)
                Text("bar")
                    .contextMenu {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("bar context destination")) {  //does not work
                            Text("bar context")
                            }
                    }
                .padding(.all)
            } //VStack
        } //NavigationView
    } //body
} //ContentView
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep "bar" in a NavigationLink.  Removing the NavigationLink from "bar" does fix the problem with "bar context", but I need a way to navigate both from "bar" and "bar context" to their respective destinations.

Comment: seems to not work anymore in xcode 12, ios14; the NavigationLink does not guide to the defined view, instead just nothing happens